# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am building a website using Flask and when I try to log in and signup I get this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_active'`

an error like this appears when I have used `login_user` in the `flask_login`  library

here I use firestore database

I have tried various solutions on StackOverflow but none of them worked, I'm very confused now
this is my code

`__ini__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_login import LoginManager
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'adjadlkahd'
    
    db = connect_database()

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    from .models import User
    #check user login
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    #create user model
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.get_user_id(id)
    #register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    
 
    return app

cred = credentials.Certificate("websites\serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def connect_database():
    db = firestore.client()
    return db
```

`auth.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.log_in(email)
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user[0].to_dict()['password'], password):
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                return "<h1>paass salah</h1>"
        else:
            return "<h1>user tidak ada</h1>"
 
    return render_template('login.html')

@auth.route('/logout')     
@login_required 
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@auth.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email    = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        if User.check_user(email):
            return "<h1>email already exist</h1>"

        new_user = User(username=username, email=email,
                        password=generate_password_hash(password)).create_user()

        login_user(new_user, remember=True)

        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('signup.html')
```

`models.py`

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import connect_database
import uuid

db = connect_database()
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def create_user(self):
        db.collection('user').document(self.username).set({
            'id' : str(uuid.uuid4()),
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'password': self.password
        })

    def log_in(email):
        user = db.collection('user').where('email', '==', email).get()
        return user
    def check_user(email):
        user = db.collection('user').where('email', '==', email).get()
        return bool(user)
    
    def get_user_id(id):
        return db.collection('user').document(id).get()
```

`views.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    return "<h1>logged in</h1>"
```

Comment: Please show your traceback in your post.

Comment: i dont know if it will work but try setting a flag is_active= 1 while creating the user

Answer (score 0):

For flask login to work you need to have a user class that implements some properties and methods. When you use login_user method the argument should be an instance of that user class.

make user that your method def log_in(email) returns a user object not a list.

```
def log_in(email):
    user = db.collection('user').where('email', '==', email).get()
    return user  # <-- most probably is a list.
```

1. Read the items form the user collection
2. Create an instance of the user class
3. fill the properties of the user class from the collection
4. return the instance

Comment: how to create instance of the user class id data if retrieve from log_in is like this `[<google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x000001F95A8673A0>]`

Comment: according to your model, the user instance is created like this: user = User(username, email, password)